# Can't able to peer two different node on different computers

Tags: substrate-node-template, chainspec

We wan't to run multiple node on multiple devices. We use [`substrate-node-template`](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) to do that. We build the project using `cargo build --release` and follow this [Add trusted node](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/add-trusted-nodes/#prepare-to-launch-the-private-network) tutorial. We were able to generate [`chainSpec.json`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18BalzeEdhaSYjRD6PPhz-7jmOYPldGbV/view?usp=sharing) and converted to [`chainSpecRaw.json`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iCsSvkPTLpJWQJjrQOquO-fLtwSbbRmr/view?usp=sharing) after modify `aura` & `grandpa` fields. We then add keys to the keystore and run first node:

```
./target/release/node-template \
  --base-path /tmp/node01 \
  --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
  --port 30333 \
  --ws-port 9945 \
  --rpc-port 9933 \
  --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
  --validator \
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \
  --name MyNode01 \
  --password-interactive
```

[image]

On second device send `chainSpecRaw.json` file then add keys to keystore of second node and run second node:
`ip4` of device where first node running: `27.34.100.91`

```
./target/release/node-template \
  --base-path /tmp/node02 \
  --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
  --port 30334 \
  --ws-port 9946 \
  --rpc-port 9934 \
  --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
  --validator \
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \
  --name MyNode02 \
  --bootnodes /ip4/27.34.100.91/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWLk8ER6sbMAZa8uzf6YmyMo8FvpCiMgrFW4NfReez5um4 \
  --password-interactive
```

[image]

No two node peers with each other. Can you please helps us why we are having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to  me there can be 2 possible scenarios due to which this can happen:

- The most basic one is because of `firewall`, it is not allowing the connection from other system.
- The other possible scenario is you didn't provide the right IP address and  the bootnode ID, you can check that also.

Most probably it is the first case so you need to check the rules of your firewall is it accepting connections or not.

Comment: hey, @UPENDRA SINGH thanks for quick response. Do you mean on second node running device to check whether `firewall` accepting connection or not?

Comment: should we have to turn firewall off or on?

Answer (score 1):

you need to change the command add  `--ws-external` `--rpc-external` `--rpc-cors all`  in your boot node command.

```
./target/release/node-template \
  --base-path /tmp/node01 \
  --chain ./customSpecRaw.json \
  --ws-external\
  --rpc-external\
  --rpc-cors all
  --port 30333 \
  --ws-port 9945 \
  --rpc-port 9933 \
  --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
  --validator \
  --rpc-methods Unsafe \
  --name MyNode01 \
  --password-interactive
```

**you can simple run this command for boot node**

```
./target/release/node-template --base-path /data/node01 --chain ./customSpecRaw.json --port 30333 --ws-port 9944 --rpc-port 9933  --ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --no-telemetry --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --name MyNode01
```

**for running the other nodes**

```
`**binary-path**` --base-path /data/node2 --chain ./customSpecRaw.json --port 30334 --ws-port 9945 --rpc-port 9934 --ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --no-telemetry --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --name MyNode002 --bootnodes /ip4/`**ip-of first computer**`/tcp/30333/p2p/`**node-identity**`.
```

**in your case run this command after running your boot-node**

```
 ./target/release/node-template --base-path /data/node2 --chain ./customSpecRaw.json --port 30334 --ws-port 9945 --rpc-port 9934 --ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --no-telemetry --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --name MyNode002 --bootnodes /ip4/27.34.100.91/tcp/30333/p2p/12D3KooWLk8ER6sbMAZa8uzf6YmyMo8FvpCiMgrFW4NfReez5um4
```

Comment: Error: Service(Client(Backend("Failed to create RocksDB directory: `Os { code: 30, kind: ReadOnlyFilesystem, message: \"Read-only file system\" }`.")))

Comment: got this issue while run command for boot node @Amit Kumar yadav

Comment: @Ganesh11 are you running it on local computer? or on instance?

Comment: on local computer

Comment: delete the db and re run the command or  run this command
./target/release/node-template --base-path /data/node001 --chain ./customSpecRaw.json --port 30333 --ws-port 9944 --rpc-port 9933  --ws-external --rpc-external --rpc-cors all --no-telemetry --validator --rpc-methods Unsafe --name MyNode001

Comment: I didn't understand even If i run the 2nd command still same issue. Which permission of read and write are you pointing. I am confused

Comment: @Ganesh11 the error occurred  because you haven't deleted the db of the previous node which you have run. you need to delete the node01 & node02 folder and run this command again it will work fine.

Comment: @Ganesh11, have you any resolution for this? 

even if I run my two nodes locally, nodes haven't producing and finalizing new blocks

Comment: @Mojo what the issue are you facing?

Comment: hey @AmitKumarYadav
I can run the two nodes locally, but when I am trying to run nodes in two different systems or instances it does not working
what type of procedure do we need to follow for this

Comment: @Mojo you need to check the command? can you share the command so that i can check?